# How do physics engine check if two objects belong to compatible categories for collisions?

Tags: c++, c++11

To be clear, this question is not about geometry or about the actual physics of collision detection, but determining if two object belong to compatible categories for colliding (nothing to do with the actual physics part).

Take a look at this image:

[image: I belong to category 0, and I collide with everything else]

Many physics engines (Box2d etc) follow such a system, where they allow you to define which category (Cat.) that an object belongs to, and the Mask - the categories of objects that it can collide with, and based on this determine if a collision should take place. I'm trying to implement the same, as I have an analogous problem, and need only this (no physics).

For example, an object (Object1) may belong to multiple categories - 0,1,2,3 and collide with categories (Mask), 5,8,9. Another Object (Object2), can belong to category (5), and collide only with Category (3). In this case a collision between Object1 and Object2 can take place.

Additional example, an object (Object1) may belong to multiple categories - 0,1,2,3 and collide with categories (Mask), 5,8,9. Another Object (Object2), can belong to category (5), and collide only with Category (4). In this case a collision between Object1 and Object2 will not take place, because although Object1 is interested in colliding with objects in category 5, Object2 is not interested in colliding with any of Object1's categories.

***The collisions will take place only if A collides with B, and B collides with A.***

I am trying to implement something which does the same, and am trying to figure out the data structure and algorithm to use, to efficiently check if two objects should "collide", according to the above logic. By efficiently, I mean use minimal memory and cpu required, so that I can do this check every clock tick - I am not trying to optimize specifically for memory or cpu, but simply find a solution that doesn't use more than it requires of each!

Here is the algorithm and data structures I've considered so far:

```
std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_set<GameObject*>> categoryToObject
std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_set<GameObject*>> maskToObject
std::unordered_map<GameObject*,std::unordered_set<GameObject*> objectsItCollidesWith
```

**Algorithm:**

Each time a new GameObject is created, for every category and mask it belongs to, it is added to the appropriate vector in each map. That means an object with Cat{1,3,7} & Mask{2,7} would be added to three vectors in the Cat map and two vectors in the mask map.

Just before adding to each map, for a new object, iterate through the categories of the new object, and use each category as a key in maskToObject, to see which gameObjects are interested in colliding with it. For each of these objects, check their category, and see if any of their categories fall into the mask that this object collides with. If that is the case, then add this object to a set of objects that this object collides with, and vice versa for the other object.

This way, as long as the categories / masks don't change, we just need to refer to the objectItCollidesWith map.

Is there a more efficient way than this ? Since the initial calculation needs to be done only once, and doesn't need to be done again unless the category / mask changes and I thought this was good.

Comment: Seems like the kind of question that's going to generate largely opinion-based answers.  However, I would suggest that storing lists of objects for every single bit is very inefficient on memory.  What I would intuitively gravitate towards if writing a collider, is first using efficient space subdivision techniques to reduce the number of objects requiring tests, and then simply use bitwise techniques to determine whether a collision should be calculated between any two objects.  It's very likely that this is why the categories and masks are explicitly presented as _bits_ in your example.

Comment: @paddy - this question has nothing to do with physics or geometry. It is about the efficient way to determine if two objects belong to the same category or not. It should not be opinion based because you can compare the algorithmic complexity, as well as memory complexity. Request you to please delete your comment, as it distracts from the actual question my post is asking.

Comment: @paddy - this question is precisely about determining if a collision should be calculated between two objects or not. (not about the physics).

Comment: I stand by my comment.  You are assuming that these bit sets are the only relevant part of an efficient collider.  I'm saying that the fact these are represented as bits at all should tell you something about the types of mechanism that may utilize this information.  The whole point of utilizing bits and masks is for small storage and quick testing.  Your proposed usage does not to this, but instead segments that space into one list per bit.  If you believe that I am wrong, then this question is more related to [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: When I talk about space subdivision, I'm talking about algorithms too.  Nothing to do with physics or even geometry.  It's more to do with filtering techniques to reduce the search space.

Comment: @paddy I'm repeating again - space subdivision is a separate problem which is not part of this question. This question is specifically about how to check if two objects belong to compatible categories. Please delete your comments as they are distracting from the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the solution I came up with.

Included only the part of my CollisionDetector class that is used for computing if two objects are in compatible categories for collision. Unlike the bitwise example, which I assume was used to quickly check all objects against each other, I think mine will be faster, since I check only against compatible categories and masks, rather than all objects.

The actual physics part - space subdivision, or checking for overlaps of objects is not relevant to this question, so not included.

```
typedef enum{
    COLLISION_CATEGORY_NO_CAT = 0, //Used only for looping.
    
    COLLISION_CATEGORY_PLAYER,
    COLLISION_CATEGORY_GROUND,
    
    COLLISION_CATEGORY_END_CAT, //Used only for looping.
}COLLISION_CATEGORIES;

class CollisionDetector{
private:
    
    std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_set<GameObject*>> categoryToObject; //Each gameObject belongs to the category key
    std::unordered_map<int,std::unordered_set<GameObject*>> maskToObject; //Each gameObject contains the key as a mask

public:
    
    CollisionDetector(){
        for (int i = COLLISION_CATEGORY_NO_CAT + 1; i<COLLISION_CATEGORY_END_CAT; i++ ){
            std::unordered_set<GameObject*> o;
            categoryToObject[i] = o;
            maskToObject[i] = o;
        }
    }
    
    void addObject(GameObject* o){
        auto objectCategories = o->getCategories();
        auto objectMasks = o->getMasks();

        //Check if A collides with B, and B collides with A. If so, make both objects keep note of each other.
        for(auto& mask : objectMasks){
            
            if(categoryToObject.find(mask)!=categoryToObject.end()){
                //Get the objects whose category matches the mask.
                auto& setOfObjectsWithCategoryMatchingMaskOfO = categoryToObject[mask];
                
                for(auto otherObject : setOfObjectsWithCategoryMatchingMaskOfO){
                    
                    //Check if this objects category is in the other objects mask
                    auto otherObjectsMasks = otherObject->getMasks();
                    for(auto& thisObjectsCategory : objectCategories){
                        if(otherObjectsMasks.find(thisObjectsCategory) != otherObjectsMasks.end()){
                            
                            //Set both objects to collide with each other
                            o->addGameObjectICollideWith(otherObject);
                            otherObject->addGameObjectICollideWith(o);
                            
                            //If even one of this objects category, is in the other objects mask, then we have fullfilled the condition that this objects category is in the other objects mask, and the other objects category is in this objects mask.
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        
        //Add this object to each of the sets of objects with these categories, so other objects can do the first part of this function.
        for(auto cat : objectCategories){
            auto& s = categoryToObject[cat];
            s.insert(o);
        }

        //Add this object to each of the sets of objects with these masks, so other objects can do the first part of this function.
        for(auto mask : objectMasks){
            auto& s = maskToObject[mask];
            s.insert(o);
        }
    }
    
    void removeObject(GameObject* o){
        auto c = o->getCategories();
        for(auto cat : c){
            auto& s = categoryToObject[cat];
            s.erase(o);
        }
        
        auto m = o->getMasks();
        for(auto mask : m){
            auto& s = maskToObject[mask];
            s.erase(o);
        }
        
        o->removeMyselfFromObjectsICollideWith();
    }
};
```

GameObject Class:

```
class GameObject{
private:
    std::unordered_set<GameObject*> _gameObjectsICollideWith;
    std::unordered_set<int> _categoriesIBelongTo;
    std::unordered_set<int> _masksICollideWith;
    
public:
    Sprite* sprite = nullptr;
    
    //TODO: Do Zorder
    GameObject(Node* parent, const Vec2& initialPosition,std::string frameName){
        sprite = Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(frameName);
        parent->addChild(sprite);
        sprite->setPosition(initialPosition);
    }
    
    ~GameObject(){
        for(auto otherObject : _gameObjectsICollideWith){
            otherObject->removeGameObjectICollideWith(this);
        }
        
        if(sprite!=nullptr){
            if(sprite->getParent()){
                sprite->removeFromParent();
            }
        }
    }
    
    std::unordered_set<int> getCategories(){
        return _categoriesIBelongTo;
    }
    
    std::unordered_set<int> getMasks(){
        return _masksICollideWith;
    }
    
    void setCategories(const std::unordered_set<int>& categories){
        _categoriesIBelongTo = categories;
    }
    
    void setMasks(const std::unordered_set<int>& masks){
        _masksICollideWith = masks;
    }
    
    void addGameObjectICollideWith(GameObject* o){
        _gameObjectsICollideWith.insert(o);
    }
    
    void removeGameObjectICollideWith(GameObject* o){
        _gameObjectsICollideWith.erase(o);
    }
    
    void removeMyselfFromObjectsICollideWith(){
        for(auto other : _gameObjectsICollideWith){
            other->removeGameObjectICollideWith(this);
        }
        
        _gameObjectsICollideWith.clear();
    }
};
```